# Filtering a List view in an ASP.MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to implement filtering in a List view based on the value in a DropDownList, in a sort of 'postback' call, where the user selects dropdown values and clicks a Refresh button.  I have figured out that I should use my ViewData for the model being listed, but how do I pass the selected values back to the Index override that takes filter parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put your dropdown in a form that has GET as it's method.  You would then generate a URL that looks like `http://mysite.com/controller/action/?filterView=ByName`  This allows your end users to bookmark their filtered results for quick reference.  You could also create a new route if you didn't want the ? in the URL.

Your controller would be something similar to below (up to you to define your filtering logic as I don't know if you are doing date ranges, getting rid of duplicates, whatever).  This assumes you are filtering by a column.

```
public ActionResult Index(string filterView = "")
    {
        var items = _repository.getItems();
        // filter you items based on the filterView string
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterView ))
        {
            //do your filtering logic here
            items = items.where(c=>c.FilterColumn = filterView);
        }
        //return the view with the items that result from the above operation or 
        //just the full list if no filtering was done
        return View(items);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Routing API](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx).  You can configure a new route in your `Global.asmx.cs` that means that calls to the Index action on your controller with a certain URL format will be sent to the correct controller.

It **might** just work as long as the name of the parameter submitted matches the name of parameters in your action method, but I'm less sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

ProfK - you could do it a couple of ways, tho i note that you mention a 'sort of postback' approach. in this case, you'd be best to do exactly that - postback the filter values and 'parse' them in the controller index method. something along the lines of this might be an approach:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string sComboValPerson = Request.Form["personfilter"];
        // now do something with this value if it is't null
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sComboValPerson ))
        {
            var items = _repository.Search(Model, sComboValPerson );
            return View(items);
        }
        else
        // return some kind of not found content or the 'normal' view
        return View();
    }
```